# Is there anyway makes me able to distribute ios app for testing without apple developer program?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipa

I developed an iOS app with xCode/swift and i want to test it on many devices remotely before uploading on store , Is there anyway i can use to distribute this app without enroll in apple developing program?
P.S. I am using diawi.com to send the app and I think it needs Ad hoc provisioning profile? is that true also?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because developer-centric questions about application stores are considered off-topic here on SO as discussed in [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway i can use to distribute this app without enroll in apple developing program?

A big NO:), it is not possible.

> I am using diawi.com to send the app and I think it needs Ad hoc provisioning profile?

No, Adhoc profile not needed. You can upload on diawi.com `.ipa` or `.zip(a zip file of .app)`. So to upload a `.ipa` you will need either dev. or production profile but for .app you do not need Adhoc, just development profile is enough. At least dev. profile is needed.